# Incorporating ISO 8859-1 Symbols / foreign languages into a WinForms application

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I have a function that finds any ISO 8859-1 symbol within a given string, and tries converting it to its proper meaning. However, I get question marks instead where I'd like actual values like: ÿ é æ etc.

Can you point me in the right direction on how to properly handle foreign/unique symbols?

Comment: "Proper meaning"? What exactly are you talking about here? .NET is completely Unicode-aware; you shouldn't even have to put up with ancient encodings unless absolutely necessary for interoperability with other things.

Comment: Eek.. I'm embarrassed here. I was importing a text file into an array of values, and when I looked at the array in debugger, all of the foreign symbols were showing up as "<?>". It turns out it works perfectly fine. Sorry about all the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the wording of your question, it sounds like you are attempting to identify byte values in a string and then convert them - this won't work. Strings are composed of characters and each character can consist of more than one byte (depending on the encoding). In other words, the conversion from a stream of bytes to a human-readable string is already performed by the time you access a string.

Have a look at the [System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hf4sb8(v=VS.100).aspx) class. If you really do want to convert a byte stream from one encoding to another, try System.Text.Encoding.Convert().

But it would be nice to know more details about your specific task so that people can give you a more precise answer.